# Js деобфускация функции

Tags: javascript

```
function Bi() {
var BV = [];
Object.defineProperty(BV, "p", {
    value: [].pop
});
Object.defineProperty(BV, "E", {
    value: [].push
});
Object.defineProperty(BV, "G", {
    value: [].slice
});
Object.defineProperty(BV, "n", {
    value: [].splice
});
return BV}
```

Как можно упростить данную функцию?

Comment: а что не так с приведенной функцией? Какую именно часть хочется упростить?

Comment: типа так: var BV = [ p {pop;}, E {push;}, G {slice;}, n {splice;}];

Comment: не, так нельзя. Максимум можно использовать `Object.defineProperties` и в один вызов все 4 свойства присвоить